# Download only if data has changed on server

Tags: ios, alamofire

I was wondering if Alamofire can check the server if previously downloaded data has changed and if it has changed then download that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is ETag, check if it has changed on server using `.HEAD` and header `"If-None-Match":"ETag"` and if you get status code 304 - data has not changed